# Is a SharedIndexInformer's Indexer's ThreadSafeStore ever emptied?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm carefully making my way through the Go code in the [`tools/cache` package](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/tools/cache) for what seems like the hundredth time.

From close-reading the code, when you create a new `SharedIndexInformer`, the following things happen:

1. `SharedIndexInformer` [creates a new `Indexer`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/87935b98dd4abdf6477f29baf934d6dd0aba82d4/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L83).
2. The `Indexer` so created [creates a new `ThreadSafeStore`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/store.go#L241) internally for holding representations of Kubernetes resources.
3. [`SharedIndexInformer.Run()` creates a new `DeltaFIFO` with the new `Indexer`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L192) as its second parameter.
4. [The `Indexer` supplied to the new `DeltaFIFO` therefore functions as its `KeyLister`
   and its `KeyGetter`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/delta_fifo.go#L59).  (This is used to track "prior state" for deletions; i.e. if there's an object in it but the latest sync up with Kubernetes does not contain that object, then we know it has been deleted from the cluster.)
5. The [`HandleDeltas` function](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L344) [is the one that the underlying `controller` will call](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L202) when Kubernetes resources are added, updated or deleted.
6. The `HandleDeltas` function will call the [`Add`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L360), [`Update`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L355) and [`Delete`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/03bfb9bdcfe5482795b999f39ca3ed9ad42ce5bb/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L366) methods on the `Indexer` (and, by extension, on its underlying `ThreadSafeStore`).

Let's say I write a new controller using a `SharedIndexInformer`.  Let's further say that it is watching for `Pod`s.  Let's finally say that there are 10 `Pod`s in the cluster.

Does this mean that after the `SharedIndexInformer`'s `Run` method has been called and some requisite amount of time has passed that there will be 10 JSON representations of `Pod`s in the `ThreadSafeStore`, and, further, that **none will be removed from this store until an actual deletion of one of the corresponding `Pod`s occurs in Kubernetes**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, except for the JSON part.

The Store contains native Object structs, deserialized from protobuf messages.

Comment: And although these objects are in this `ThreadSafeStore`, this is not the "cache" that most people talk about when they talk about Kubernetes operators—usually they mean a workqueue that they themselves arrange to have populated via a different mechanism (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/37c3c02ec96533daec0dbda1f39a6b1d68505c79/examples/workqueue/main.go#L178)?

Comment: It _is_ effectively a cache which allows you to read objects inside your cluster without querying the API server directly. The Informer is here to ensure the cache is always fresh. The workqueue is a separate and optional component that most operators use to "schedule" (_enqueue_) some piece of work that has to be picked up (_dequeued_) by a worker thread.